# indexOf specific characters at specific locations when reading files

Tags: java

Using indexOf after reading a file, How would one code indexOf for only specific characters before and after a word?

for example

'billy'

Single Quotes: 2

bi'lly

Single Quotes: 0

My Code

```
if ( 0 <= name.indexOf("'")){
        singleQuotes++;
```

My code will count all of the single quotes, How can I make it so when it reads a file with a bunch of words. To only get the single quotes at the beginning and end of each word?

Comment: You can't. That's not what `indexOf()` does. You would either need to use regular expressions or manually check the proceeding or following index for whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that. The expression that you need looks like this:

```
(^|\s)'|'(\s|$)

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)'|'(\\s|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("quick 'brown' fox jump's over 'the' lazy dog");
int cnt = 0;
while(m.find()) {
    cnt++;
}
System.out.println(cnt);
```

This prints out `4`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `regex`, then you can write something as below:

```
    String myString = "quick 'brown' fox jump's over 'the' lazy dog";
    int count = 0;

    String[] words = myString.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i <words.length; i++){
        if(words[i].charAt(0) == '\'' ){
            count++;
        }
        if(words[i].charAt(words[i].length()-1) == '\'' ){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```